# Can I award a bounty to a deleted answer?

Tags: discussion, bounty, deleted-answers, 10k-tools

#### Can I technically award a bounty to a deleted answer?

Now that I'm more than 10k rep, I'm noticing that deleted answers still show a bounty button. If I click on the +50, will it award it? Or will an error message pop up?

[image]

---

Corollaries:

#### If technically possible, is there a valid case where one would do this 10k+ only privilege action?

#### If technically possible, how many times did it happen in the past on Stack Overflow?

Comment: It shouldn't be technically possible, so no...

Comment: related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169225/why-does-the-bounty-award-button-appear-on-deleted-answers

Comment: @SurajRao good find :)

Comment: times like this.. wish we could close as cross site dupe :p @JonClements

Comment: wouldnt the right action be to undelete it first?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I tried it. And as pointed out by Suraj Rao and Jon Clements, it's technically not possible.

First, I get the popup question:

> Are you sure you want to award your bounty to this answer? THIS CANNOT BE UNDONE!

[image]

But then I get an error:

> This post has been deleted; deleted posts can't be voted on

[image]

Cross-site related: [Why does the bounty award button appear on deleted answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169225/why-does-the-bounty-award-button-appear-on-deleted-answers)

Comment: Don't forget tt award yourself the answer (but don't delete the question before you do ;-)

Answer (score 8):

It may not be possible directly,  but I deleted [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41372145/4752675) to a bounty question and was awarded the bounty anyway.   The person who offered the bounty could see my (deleted) answer and contacted the moderators. They undeleted my answer so that he could award the bounty.

Comment: OK, so now the question becomes: if you delete the answer again, do you lose the bounty too, or only the rep from the upvotes?

Comment: @MrLister You lose any rep gained from that answer unless the answer is old enough (60 days I believe)